# In Reactjs, Close other items when one item is opened

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie in reactjs and trying to make accordion menu.

How to close other items when one item is opened?

This is what I tried so far.

```
 .accordion-cnt { display: none; }
 .accordion-cnt.on { display: block; }


const ListItem = (props) => {
  const [showAccordion, setShowAccordion] = React.useState(false);
  const onToggleAccordion = () => {
    setShowAccordion(!showAccordion);
  };
  return (
    <li className={`accordion-item ${showAccordion ? "on" : ""}`}>
      <button onClick={onToggleAccordion}>
       title
      </button>
      <div className={`accordion-cnt ${showAccordion ? "on" : ""}`}>
        content
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};  
const Menu2 = () => {
  return (
    <>  
      <ul className="accordion-list"> 
        <ListItem />
        <ListItem /> 
      </ul> 
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Move the "open" state to a common ancestor component as the source of truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. The `id` can also be any unique field from an array in case your accordion list is formed using things like `array.map`.

```
const ListItem = ({ id, show, onShow }) => {
  const handleShow = () => onShow && onShow(id);

  return (
    <li className={`accordion-item ${show ? "on" : ""}`}>
      <button onClick={handleShow}>
        title
      </button>
      <div className={`accordion-cnt ${show ? "on" : ""}`}>
        content
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

const Menu2 = () => {
  const [showId, setShowId] = useState();
  
  const handleShow = id => setShowId(id);

  return (
    <>
      <ul className="accordion-list">
        <ListItem id={1} show={showId === 1} onShow={handleShow} />
        <ListItem id={2} show={showId === 2} onShow={handleShow} />
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```